# Set Text To the currently being used EditText on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have 3 EditText and 3 Buttons, I know how to setText to a particular EditText , but what I want is to setText to the EditText that is currently being used. i.e when I click button 1 then which ever EditText I am currently in should be set to a particular Text, is it possible ?? or should I have individual buttons for each of EditText so that on each button I click, I update only a particular EditText

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a variable to store which is the current EditText or you can call [getCurrentFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29) on the parent view to get the current element in focus

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you could use a `OnFocusChangeListener` and apply it to all your `EditTexts`. e.g.

```
public class A {

    private EditText selectedEditText;

    private void setupEditTexts(){
        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(changeListener);
        ...
    }

    private OnFocusChangeListener changeListener= new OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) selectedEditText = (EditText)v;
        }
    };

}
```

Then when your `Button` is clicked, just link to the selected `EditText`.

Note: not only can it be null, but if focus changes to another `View`, this won't track it, but will instead point to the last `EditText` that was focused.